# Stock for quantities over quantities 100 go up randomly - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory

I have a problem whereby stock quantities with 3 or more digits (100 or more) go up randomly on my site.

I am not sure what the problem could be. Stock quantity increments are disabled on every level.

Comment: What do you mean by "they go up randomly", the stock amount itself gets changed randomly? Have you checked that there are no other modules interacting with the stock?

Comment: Is there any kind of pattern to when they change and by how much?

Comment: @SantiBM yes, the amount gets changed randomly. There aren't any modules interacting with the stock.

Comment: @DominicXigen there isn't a pattern. It's all random and they go up and down randomly by a random quantity.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating this issue for over a week I finally decided to delete and re-add the affected SKUs. This solution worked!